# How to use await on the sqlcommand object?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I do want to execute an asynchronous SQL statement with the new .NET 4.5 await function.

This is how I have it now:

```
dim cmd as new SqlCommand("exec longproc",connection)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

Now when the code executes it will wait and freeze the main window thread until the statement is made.

How do I do this asynchronous using await, so the window is waiting for the statement, but it is not frozen?

Answer (score 4):

use [`cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonqueryasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)